# Control class for an entity

Tags: java, design-patterns, functional-programming, mvc, lambda

For a `Student` object in the package `entity`, I have a `control.student`package with classes that are relevant to the `Student` object.

The `Student` is a class with only private properties and getters/setters for every property. **The setters do no validation on their own.**

My project structure is as follows:

```
src/
  control/
    student/
      StudentControl.java
      StudentValidator.java
      ValidationError.java
  entity/
     Student.java
```

`ValidationError` is just a `String` wrapper with getters and setters.

The `StudentValidator` is a functional interface that extends `Function<Student, Optional<ValidationError>>`.

```
interface StudentValidator extends Function<Student, Optional<ValidationError>> {}
```

The `StudentControl` class is as follows:

```
package control.student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import entity.Student;

public class StudentControl {

  private static final Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("[aA-zZ]+");

  /**
   * List of functions that validate a Student.
   */
  private static final List<StudentValidator> validatorFunctions = new ArrayList<>();
  static {
    validatorFunctions.add(validateNamesFunction());
  }

  /**
   * Validates a Student's fields.
   * 
   * @param student Student to validate
   * @return an Optional that may contain a List of ValidationError. Those ValidationError(s) will
   *         have error messages describing each error occurred while validating the student.
   */
  public static Optional<List<ValidationError>> validate(Student student) {
    List<ValidationError> errors = validatorFunctions.stream()
        .map(f -> f.apply(student))
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return errors.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(errors);
  }

  /**
   * Returns a function that validates a Student's name.
   */
  public static StudentValidator validateNamesFunction() {
    return student -> {
      return namePattern.matcher(student.getName()).matches()
          ? Optional.empty()
          : Optional.of(new ValidationError("Invalid name"));
    };
  }

  /**
   * Returns a function that validates a Student's birth date.
   */
  public static StudentValidator validateBirthDateFunction() {
    return student -> {
      return student.getBirthDate().getTime() > new Date().getTime()
          ? Optional.of(new ValidationError("Student was born in the future."))
          : Optional.empty();
    };
  }

  /**
   * Returns a function that validates a Student's join date.
   */
  public static StudentValidator validateJoinDateFunction() {
    return student -> {
      return student.getJoinDate().getTime() > new Date().getTime()
          ? Optional.of(new ValidationError("Student joined in the future."))
          : Optional.empty();
    };
  }
}
```

Is this code readable? Does it easily convey to the programmer what it is meant to do? **Does it comply with the MVC pattern?** How could I change my code to make it look, feel and run better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Creating validators

I think it's perfectly readable. However, there's a lot of repetition.

To make creating validators simpler and more declarative, you could take it one step further and lift the test/return-Optional logic into a higher-order function:

```
public class StudentControl {

  public static final StudentValidator namesValidator = validator(
    student -> namePattern.matcher(student.getName()).matches(),
    "Invalid name"
  );

  ...

  private static StudentValidator validator(Predicate<Student> pred, String error) {
    return student -> pred.test(student)
      ? Optional.empty()
      : Optional.of(error);
  }
}
```

and then if you have other models besides `Student`, you might genericize the validators.

```
interface EntityValidator<T> extends Function<T, Optional<ValidationError>> {}

public abstract class EntityControl<T> {
  protected final List<EntityValidator<? super T>> validators = new ArrayList();

  protected EntityValidator<T> validator(Predicate<T> pred, String error) {
    return x -> pred.test(x)
      ? Optional.empty()
      : Optional.of(error);
  }

  // Or, if you want to allow any subclass to create a validator for any type,
  // it could be static:
  protected static <T> EntityValidator<T> validator(...)

  public Optional<List<ValidationError>> validate(T entity) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This feels a bit cleaner to me as far as separation of concerns, but if you're only ever going to validate `Student`s it's probably overkill.

#### Other

You might also consider having `validate()` return an `Optional<Set<ValidationError>>` instead of the List, if order isn't important. Since validation errors are just strings, you can't effectively do any further handling of them, so I assume they just get piped out to the user somehow?

> Does it comply with the MVC pattern?

I'm not an MVC expert, but: what is the view supposed to be? You haven't included anything that displays `Student`s or errors, receives input, or otherwise does anything with `Student`s, so it's hard to thoroughly assess this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I definitely like the EntityControl class. However I would suggest changing the methods to be non-static as the generic class T is non-static, otherwise there will be a compilation error.

Comment: Good catch, thanks, I've updated that with two working alternatives.